# Redirect to own site when user logs in via Facebook app

Tags: authentication, facebook

I am building an app with the functionality to publish 
messages to users walls while specific actions runs on 
my website.

What I have done is (briefly):

1. Registered my own app on Facebook
2. Added a login button on my website with permission 
   to publish:

Log in on Facebook

1. Downloaded facebook-php-sdk library

It is now I start having problems. I do not know how 
to do what I want to do now.

What I want to do:

When a user logs on to facebook via my website. I want 
a file on my site to be called, where I can update the 
user's data in my own database as well.

Because that is not what the canvas url is meant to do? How it 
is no, seems no file at all is called on my site when 
I click on Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the [Facebook PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php) you noticed that there are two options for the users to login:

- Using the XFBML button, which will:

  1. Open a login dialog (pop-up) asking for permissions..etc
  2. When a successful authentication/authorization is complete the dialog will close, the `auth.login` event will be triggered and based on that the page will get reloaded `window.location.reload();`
  3. The PHP in the top of the page will get into business and <strike>`$session = $facebook->getSession();` will actually retrieve a session!</strike> `$user = $facebook->getUser();` will retrieve the current user
- Using the Login URL generated by the Library `$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();` this URL will get you through the same flow and if you noticed there's a <strike>`next`</strike> `redirect_uri` parameter which will redirect you back after a successful process to that URL (mainly the same URL you are at), where you can change that parameter if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas URL is the URL Facebook uses when it displays your application from within Facebook.  You would use this functionality if you expect users to use your application while in Facebook itself.

When authenticating using Facebook's API (assuming graph API usage here), you provide a redirect_uri as part of the authentication URL.  Once Facebook has authorized your application, it will redirect the user's web browser to the URI you specified.  This URI can be any link you desire on your site.  You should use the link as the determination of when the user is logged in successfully, e.g., https://mywebsite/facebook/loggedin.

Comment: When do I enter that redirect_uri? Right now, the login prompt window just closes down by automatic when I logs in via the log in button. Where do I provide the authentication URL?

Comment: @Peter Westerlund How are you generating the login button?  Are you creating it yourself or are you using Facebook FBML?

Comment: First, I used Facebook FBML, but then, when I tried with own link that worked better. But the Facebook button looks better. I want to use that button.